# Probability of mixed type question

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let X be a random variable of the mixed typed having the CDF

$F(x)=\begin{cases} 0, \text{x< -1} \\ \frac{x+2}{3}, \text -1 \leq x<1 \\ 1, \text 1 \leq x \end{cases}$

Find the indicated probabilities

$a). P(X<0)=0$

$b). P(x<-1)=0$

$c).P(X \leq -1)=1$

$d). P(-1 \leq x < \frac{1}{2})= P(\frac{1}{2})-P(-1)$= $\frac{5}{6}-\frac{1}{3}$

$e). P(-1<X<1)$= $\frac{2}{3}$

Are these correct?

Comment: Why do you think $P(X<0)=0$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Sorry I misinterpreted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) and d) are wrong. the others are correct/.

a) $P(X<0)=\frac  1 3 +\int_{-1}^{0} \frac 1 3 dx=\frac 2 3$. 
 For d) add $\int_0^{1/2} \frac 1 3 dx$ to $\frac 2 3$.

Comment: so for d). it is 7/8?

Comment: @Twilight I have made a correction to my answer. The answer for a) is $\frac 2 3 $ and the answer for d) is $\frac  5  6$.